# Tensor multiplication library

Tags: c

I am writing a scientific code in c which requires numerous tensor products, and higher-order tensor operations as well, e.g. contraction, kronecker product, etc.  I am planning on implementing this myself using efficient algorithms as in the literature and employing a good BLAS library.  I did some looking about and haven't really found anything for c (plenty for c++, python etc.).  Am I missing something or has this really not been well implemented in c?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you could investigate [tensor extensions](http://snow.phys.uwm.edu/tensor/) to the [GSL](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/) — GNU Scientific Library.

Comment: Not quite what I'm looking for, but the best I have found.  Thanks.

Comment: I've been working on a generic Array class that can be used for tensor operations. You can find it [here](https://code.google.com/p/cpp-array/).

Comment: @Mosby I am curious why you accepted an answer that was not quite what you're looking for.  It discourages future responses if you accept an answer.

Answer (score 6):

There are many different uses of tensors in scientific computing, so this question is hard to answer without more details.

There is a related answer on [SciComp](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/11276/fast-lightweight-c-tensor-library-for-dimension-agnostic-code) that mentions Eigen, Armadillo, deal.II, libtensor and libdynd.

If you are interested in contracting large tensors in parallel, look at the [Cyclops Tensor Framework](https://github.com/solomonik/ctf) (CTF), which is the back-end for multiple quantum chemistry codes.  If you want to do a large number of small contractions, CTF may not help you.

Other open-source tensor libraries include [libtensor](http://iopenshell.usc.edu/downloads/tensor/) and [TiledArray](https://github.com/ValeevGroup/tiledarray), which are also used in quantum chemistry.

The [MADNESS](https://github.com/m-a-d-n-e-s-s/) project has [a tensor class](https://github.com/m-a-d-n-e-s-s/madness/tree/master/src/madness/tensor) that might meet your needs if small dimensions are of interest.

[itensor](http://itensor.org/) is another tensor library, which aims to support DMRG computations.

[FTensor](http://www.wlandry.net/Projects/FTensor) is a C++ tensor library oriented at general relativity.

Because tensors operations are important to machine learning, companies like Facebook and Google have released tensor libraries such as [THPP](https://github.com/facebook/thpp) and [TensorFlow](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow), respectively.

There is a very old project called [POOMA](http://www.nongnu.org/freepooma/) that might [support small tensors](http://www.nongnu.org/freepooma/tutorial/tut-04.html#tiny) to meet your needs, but this project is no longer active and you should expect no support whatsoever.

When all else fails, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_software) or Google (about half of the information here was identified by searching for "tensor library" on Google, although I have historical familiarity with most of it).

Answer (score 0):

You could also use Elemental 
http://libelemental.org/about/

even though it is written in C++, it also has a C interface:
"The C++11 API is by far the most complete, but a large percentage of the library is also exposed to C and Python interfaces. "

On a side note, use the latest version on the developing branch on the github page:
https://github.com/elemental/Elemental/

I encountered some issues about some compatibilities that were solved using the latest version!